# Overload resolution ambiguity on the number of lambda parameters

Tags: kotlin, overload-resolution

The following lines produces an `Overload resolution ambiguity` compiler error:

```
class Req {}
class Rsp {}

fun get(filter: (Req, Rsp) -> Unit) {
  filter(Req(), Rsp())
}

fun get(init: Req.()-> Unit) {
  val req = Req()
  req.init()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  get {
    println("Overload resolution ambiguity")
  }

  get {req, rsp ->
    println("OK")
  }
}
```

The first **get** produces the `Overload resolution ambiguity` compiler error, but I don't understand why? It is clear which function I'm referring to, isn't?

The workaround is to being explicit and add an `->`:

```
get {->
  println("OK")
}
```

This fix the problem, but of course doesn't look as good as previous version.

Seems a compiler bug to me.

Thanks.

Kotlin: 1.1.0

Comment: If you think it should be fixed/improved, please report it as a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT